# Draw a Chart.js with data retrieved through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I want to use Chart.js to draw a pie chart. I want to create the chart dynamically, because the user first needs to make some selection that will filter the data being used in the chart.

I have a canvas on the page:

```
<canvas id="PieChart"width="54" height="27" style="display: block; width: 54px; height: 27px;"></canvas>
```

and I have the code to do the ajax call

```
$('.rappofiler').change(function() {
         console.log('render report');
         $.ajax({
             url: "../controllers/reportController.php",
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'html',
             data: {
                 'action': 'openIssues',
                 'filter1' : $('#filter1').val(),
                 'filter2' : $('#filter2').val()
             }
         }).done(function (chartdata) {

             var parsedChartdata =  $.parseJSON(chartdata);

            // now draw the chart

     })
```

The ajax call will get json back that looks like this:

```
[{"description":"team1","number":11},{"description":"team2","number":408},{"description":"team3","number":12}]
```

The number of returned values will vary. I now somehow have to combine the result of the ajax call, with code to draw the pie chart like this:

```
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]
        }]
};
```

What would be the best way to do this? keeping in mind that I can't change the way the data is returned after the ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having a lot of trouble to find a nice way to do it, I ended up doing it like this and then just assigning the 'labels' and 'data' array to the according properties in the data variable for the chart.

```
var output = [{'description': 'team1','number': 11},{'description':'team2','number': 408}, {'description': 'team3','number': 12}];

var labels = [];
var data = [];

output.forEach(function(entry) {
  labels.push(entry.description);
  data.push(entry.number);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bn32gh94/2/

Let me know if there's something wrong with the fiddle because it's literally the first one I make public. :)

Comment: The fiddle works, thanks! This way is kind of the way I was thinking about doing it, but it seems so ugly to just concatenate strings, and I though the java guru's out here would maybe know a "prettier" way to do it.

Comment: Would like to hear a better solution to this as well, indeed!

Comment: actually, you're not concatenating strings, you're using push to add them to the array, that's already a lot better than what I had in mind

Comment: Oh God no, concatenating strings would indeed be ugly. But then again, I don't know how you'd pass them to the chart variable because afaik it only takes an array.